# JavaScript Regex immediate end should not be a digit

Tags: javascript, regex

I am validating the input text with specific text "ABC 1234" in a sentence using javascript regex expression.
My desired text can be occurred at begin, middle or end of the sentence or line. the text can be upper or lower case.

My desired validation:
ex:

- "hdkjd  dldld f abc 1234" - valid
- "jkdlfd df    kdkd  333 abc 1234 dkdk dfd 444 d" - valid
- "dkdkf f fd kkd  dfabc1234" - valid
- "kdkdfjf dkf  dfk . fd,f kd  abc 1234,kdf" - valid
- "kdkdfjf dkf  dfk . fd,f kd  abc 1234.kdf" - valid
- "kdkdfjf dkf  dfk . fd,f kd  abc 1234kdf" - valid
- "kdkdfjf dkf  dfk . fd,f kd  abc 1234, 5" - valid
- "kdkdfjf dkf  dfk . fd,f kd  abc 12345kdf" - invalid
- "kdkdfjf dkf  dfk . fd,f kd  abc 12345" - invalid

I have tried below expression, but its failing if there is any digit after 1234.

```
/[\.\,\s]*A[\.\,\s]*B[\.\,\s]*C[\.\,\s]*1[\.\,\s]*2[\.\,\s]*3[\.\,\s]*4([\.\,\s]*|[\.\,\s]+[a-z]+)/i
```

Here is the RegExr Link: [RegExr](http://regexr.com/5pl6k)

Kindly suggest me to fix this error.

Comment: You don't need to escape `,`, and you don't need to escape `.` inside `[]`.

Comment: Why is the third line valid? It's missing `4`.

Comment: @Barmar yes, i have edited with 4. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, i do not want any other words between 'C' and '1'. whitespace, dot and comma can allow. I am facing only the problem with a number immediate after 1234.

Comment: I deleted my comment because I misread one of the examples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a negative lookahead after `4` that disallows a digit there.

```
/*A[.,\s]*B[.,\s]*C[.,\s]*1[.,\s]*2[.,\s]*3[.,\s]*4(?!\d)([.,\s]*|[.,\s]+[a-z]+)/i
```

There's no need for `[.,\s]*` at the beginning. Unless the regexp is anchored, it will match anywhere in the string. And since ``[.,\s]*` matches an empty string, it has no effect on whether the regexp as a whole matches.

[regexr](https://regexr.com/5plcb)

Comment: Thank you for your help! its fullfilled my requirement. Even i have tried the not allow digit expression earlier, but i think i forgot use the braces the expression. But now its working. Thank you for help! :-)